# 14 pins connector type

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to find the following connector. I have searched multiple platforms but cannot find the right wire to board connector. The pitch is 2 mm, and it has 14 pins.

[image: front]

[image: back]

[image: side]

[image: top]

Comment: That looks like a pretty standard 14 pin 2.54mm pitch header. Are you certain the pitch is 2.00mm?

Comment: The pitch is 2 mm, I was not able to find the one with that green thing on the front that clicks the connector. Do you have a type number?

Comment: The physical tab on it? That is proving harder to find than I'd expected....

Comment: Exactly! I have the same problem for a while now.

Comment: If this is a one-time project consider cutting the shroud off and using alternative methods (if even necessary) to secure the plug and socket.  If you are talking about production quantities - I would look for completely different parts.

Comment: It looks hand soldered. If it’s a small company you could probably just ask them to look it up on their schematic.

Comment: Seconding @st2000. You should be able to find different, more readily-available parts without too much trouble, and that looks like it will probably mate with a standard header connector.

Comment: That is my last option, was hoping it was just a regular connector and I wasn't able to find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like anything I encountered before. Close to Molex 87831 series but different lock.
I am pretty sure you can replace this header with Molex 87831 or JST PHD series connector, and there are plenty of already wired plugs for those available.